# Sync does not import all users from AD

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, 2016, active-directory-import

I have a SharePoint 2016 single server farm.
My User Profile Service Application is configured to use the SharePoint Active Directory Import.

I have configured a new Synchronization Connection and set a user with Reading and Replicating Directory Changes permissions.

Then I start a Full Synchronization but nothing is added or updated.

What is missing?

Comment: Is user profile service instance running on the server?check this from system settings > maange services on server..? which min role u are using?

Comment: Resolved. I configured MIM and using it I was able to have a log.
The problem was generated by wrong permission in AD and also wrong service UPS account.
Thank you to everybody for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the user profile synchronization service is provisioned properly, you should  configure `the active directory import` in `Configure Synchronization  Setting` to **Active Directory import**

[image]

**Note:** **There are two import modes:**

- `Active Directory import:` This method enables you to import user information from 
  AD DS into SharePoint user profile properties.
- `External identity manager synchronization:` SharePoint Server 2013 was bundled with the Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) Sync service to support complex user profile synchronization scenarios with different identity providers.

For more details check

- [Configuring user profiles in SharePoint 2016](https://www.nhaustralia.com.au/blog/Configuring-user-profiles-in-SharePoint-2016/)
- [SharePoint 2016 User Profile Service Step by Step](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33745.sharepoint-2016-user-profile-service-step-by-step-configuration-of-mim-2016.aspx)

Comment: But, do you have and idea why SharePoint Active Directory Import is not working correctly?

Comment: what is the current CU you have installed on your farm? what's the server role, also may be sync connection is not configured to read data from AD so check  Configure  Sync connections in CA!

Comment: Sorry, could you explain me what you mean for CU and for CA?

Comment: CU stand for Cumulative Update and CA stand for Central Administration :)

Comment: My current installation is 16.0.4510.1001 (March 14, 2017)
I created a sync connection whit a user that has Read and Replicating permisisons. I don't know if there is a way specify which connection it has to use.

Comment: okay, could you please answer the other above questions? also, please check if the UPS service account is added to farm administrator group or not ?

Comment: No, it is not! The user that I use to run the Service App Pool that contains the UPS it is not a Farm Administrator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59377/discussion-between-domenico-and-m-qassas).

Comment: I have added the UPS service account to farm administrator, but it is still not importing all users. It imports only user that have permission in any site collection

Comment: Please, check the sync connection setting, may be you don't select the root Active Directory!

Comment: In my connection, I selected the Users folder of AD.

Comment: Is this possible in SPO?